# Wide bezier path for point detection

Tags: ios, uibezierpath

I have a complex path with several Bezier segments joined together. This path is dynamic and user could add and remove points inside this path.

When I draw path, I save `UIBezierPath` copy, like this:

```
CGContextBeginPath(context);
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < _points.count - 1; i++)
{
    // ...
    CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context, cp1x, cp1y, cp2x, cp2y, endX, endY);
}
_path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:CGContextCopyPath(context)];
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

I create new point with long press gesture:

```
- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    // ...
    CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:self];
    if ([_path containsPoint:point])
    {
        // process point
    }
    // ...
}
```

But this require user to tap very close to path. I want to have wider area around path where I consider any tap to be valid (like line width).

How to configure `UIBezierPath` to allow wider area? I want it control how wide this area could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is possible solution:

```
CGPathRef pathCopy = CGContextCopyPath(context);
// 16 is the width of path where we want to have hit test
CGPathRef tapPath = CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath(pathCopy, NULL, 16, kCGLineCapButt, kCGLineJoinMiter, 0.6);
// this path will be used for hit test
_linePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:tapPath];
[_linePath closePath];
```

Now somewhere we need it:

```
CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:self];
if ([_linePath containsPoint:point])
{
    // work with point
}
```